# Generate token for multiple realms with Keyclock

Tags: keycloak

Is there a way to generate **the same token** for several realms in keycloak?

So that an authentication URL would look like this, for example:
`http://localhost:8888/auth/"multiple realm"/glide/protocol/openid-connect/token`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible:

> A realm manages a set of users, credentials, roles, and groups. A user belongs to and logs into a realm. **Realms are isolated from one another and can only manage and authenticate the users that they control**.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#core-concepts-and-terms (definition of "realms")

If you could explain why you want to do this, I (or someone else) could maybe suggest a better alternative.

Comment: thanks qutax for your response, my problem is i have a user who is authenticated in the first realm and he get the token of the authentication then i want the same user can access to the second realm with the token already created in the first realm.

Comment: @Crunch_BK but the user does not exist in the second realm, as realms are isolated. what's the concrete use case? Is it possible that you are mixing up realms and clients?

Comment: yes the user does not exist in the second realm but i want to authorize him to do actions in the second realm by his token that he get it in the first realm. in general every one who has valid token can access to all realms. thanks

Comment: No. That's not possible. You could develop an application / service that would connect the two realms via a technical user though (or even create duplicate users in the second realm). Every action would be performed via the service using the technical user then. But again: you would have to implement it yourself as some kind of service. Keycloak isolates realms from one another and doesn't allow this.